# Como recortar uma imagem - HTML

Tags: html, css, imagem, blogger

Preciso de fazer com que uma imagem dentro de uma `div` fique com uma largura de `600px` e uma altura de `300px` sem distorcer a imagem.

Tenho uma noção sobre css3 e html5 e estou trabalhando no layout de um blog na plataforma Blogger.
Já alterei muita coisa no código fonte do layout inicial.
E agora quero fazer é o seguinte:

Quero que na postagem apareça uma imagem de preview que seja gerada automaticamente a partir da primeira imagem do post, que no caso já programei pra acontecer isso, mas preciso que o preview tenha `width:600px` e `height:300px` sem distorcer a imagem que servirá como preview na pagina inicial.

Ela pode ser cortada, mas não distorcida, alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer isso?

Link do blog: https://www.futebolcomblush.com.br
Exemplo de como quero que a imagem fique:
http://blogdopizzato.com.br/

[image: Minha melhor tentativa frustada chegou a isto:]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Recortar imagem usando `object-fit`

Podes recortar uma imagem com a tag `img` utilizando o `object-fit` da seguinte forma:

```css
.objectImage {
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
.imagemNormal {
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
    <span>object-fit: cover; (imagem recortada)</span>
    <img class="objectImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imagem">
    <span>imagem não recortada (altura da imagem encolhe) </span>
    <img class="imagemNormal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg">
</div>
```

> Hoje em dia todos os navegadores suportam o `object-fit` exceto o Internet Explorer.
> Mais informações sobre a propriedade Object-fit nos seguintes links:
>
> - [Css-tricks object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)
> - [Mozilla object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

---

### Recortar imagem usando um *container* com as propriedades `Overflow` e `Position`

```css
.imagem-wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; /* Para fazer que a imagem com position-absolute respeite a sua posição consoante este selector, ou evitar que saia do mesmo */
}
.imagem {
    width: 600px;
    /* código abaixo centra a imagem ao centro */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem-wrapper">
    <img class="imagem" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg">
</div>
```

---

### Recortar imagem usando a imagem como background

Se estiveres a utilizar a imagem como `background-image`, também podes fazê-lo utilizando a propriedade `background-size: cover;`.

```css
.imagemBg {
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg) center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagemBg"></div>
```

---

### Alternativa

Como alternativa, se estiveres à procura de recortar uma imagem com várias medidas preparadas, podes sempre utilizar plugins, como por exemplo em jQuery tens o [resizeAndCrop](https://github.com/Traackr/resizeAndCrop).

Existem também outros plugins em PHP como o Timthumb, mas este deixou de ser aconselhável devido a problemas de segurança. Mas sempre podes pesquisar no Google por plugins à tua preferência de linguagem, PHP/JavaScript etc para encontrares o que é melhor e se adequa para as tuas necessidades.

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso?

```css
.preview {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('http://blogdopizzato.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/201501072015-Maranhao.jpg');
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview"/>
```

Se você quiser mover a imagem de dentro do `background-image`, utilize o `background-position`, exemplo:

```
background-position: 50px; /* desce 50px */
```